# Force HTML input to accept english char from barcode scanner

Tags: html, input, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have an HTML input field that accepts the scanned data from barcode scanner device, the barcode output is something like this:

```
11321-XS
11321-S
11321-M
11321-L
11321-XL
11321-XXL
```

When I focus on the input, and scan the barcode that reflects one the above items, it works only if the local language of the PC is "English", while if the language is something else (ex: Arabic), it will read "XL", "M" or any character after "-" char as strange characters.

Is there's any way to force the input to accept only "English" characters from the reader?

Comment: Did you try to specify  the character encoding for the HTML document? try to put <meta charset="UTF-8"> in your html page header?

Comment: yes I did, but didn't work!

Comment: if your doctype is not html5 you can try  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">